# GWT regex not working

Tags: java, regex, gwt, client

```
String statement1 = "<'aaa'> Hello <'bbb'> Demo <'ccc'>";

RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
    MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(statement1);
    boolean matchFound = matcher != null;

    while(matchFound){
        System.out.println("First: "+matcher.getGroup(0));
        System.out.println("Second: "+matcher.getGroup(1));
        System.out.println("Third: "+matcher.getGroup(2));
    }

  o/p:
        First:  <'aaa'>
        Second: aaa
        Third: undefined
```

This code doesn't return me expected result, which it does with util regex.

```
Expected Result Was:<aaa> <bbb> <ccc>
```

Comment: Why do you espace the < and >? There is no need

Comment: After `MatchResult matcher = ...` try adding  `statement1 = statement1.replace("<'", "<").replace("'>", ">"));` and declare the regex with `"g"`: `RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("<([^<>*)>", "g");`

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that you have 3 expected matches in the string, but you declare the regex without `global` flag "g". You do not have to escape `<` and `>` as they are not special characters.

Thus, use

```
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("<(.*?)>", "g");
                                           ^
```

or - if there can be no `<` symbol from the first `<` and the next `>`:

```
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("<([^<]*)>", "g");
```

Note that `[^<]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `<` which is more efficient than a lazy dot matching.

Note that `matcher.getGroup(n)` accesses *captured submatches* that are substrings matched with parenthesized subpatterns. Since you only have 1 set of parentheses in your regex, there are 2 groups: 1) 0th that is the whole match, and 2) the 1st group that is all between the `<` and `>`.

Now, if you expect to get rid of `'` after `<` and before `>`, I suggest removing them beforehand with a mere `replace` method.

To get all matches use:

```
while (matcher != null) {
    ...
    matcher = regExp.exec(statement1);
}
```

Comment: Please check and let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Any news? Need more help?